# Default Built-in sh read Variable Name

Tags: shell

From `$ man sh`: "`read [-p prompt] [-r] variable [...]`".  Is any default name for the requested `variable`?

I have omitted it by mistake, yet the script ran with no error, except the unexpected result, of course :) .

Answer (score 2):

The default variable for POSIX shells is `REPLY`.

Comment: Short, sweet, to the point.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : I wanted to make it shorter, but Stackoverflow requires an answer to contain a certain minimum number of characters, even when they are redundant.  ;-)

Comment: I was worried about my comment too `:)`

Comment: Great `REPLY`!  How did you find it?!  I have search `man read`, and `man sh`: no avail...  Off-topic: 15 char, yet strings of spaces are not counted.  I have tried to "Thank you     !" `;)`

Comment: @Mihai : Well, _man sh_  would show it in the section _Shell Variables_ (for instance), but this man-page is not really suited in general for your case, since (at least on  Linux), this simply displays the man-page for _bash_, while you want to know the solution for POSIX shell. In this case, you can do for instance a `man ash` or `man dash`, or better yet look up the definition on [the web](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html#top).